# "По-вашему" или "по-Вашему"? Строчная или прописная?

Tags: прописная-строчная

Я предположил, что вторая часть после дефиса может писаться с большой буквы, **только** если первая тоже пишется с большой (в названиях, например, Усть-Илимск). Верно?

---

**Увидев несогласие, решил изменить и обновить вопрос.**

---

Речь, естественно, об обращении **к одному человеку.**

Изначально я спрашивал, почему может быть только маленькая буква (*"по-вашему"*). Но оказалось, что и это спорный вопрос. Утверждая же о маленькой букве, я основывался на двух источниках, которые говорят в пользу этого варианта ([1](http://lexicon555.com/january07/question.htm), [2](http://ktvd.ru/kogda-vy-pishetsya-s-bolshoi-bukvy)), и на том, что не нашёл ничего в пользу *"по-Вашему".* Возможно, эти источники не очень авторитетны, но в пользу большой буквы я не нашёл ничего, даже таких примеров.

*Так как всё-таки правильно писать и почему?*

Comment: Артем, здесь вы найдете ответ.  http://gramma.ru/RUS/?id=8.24

Comment: Спасибо, Серж! Ну вот, ещё одно мнение, совпадающее с теми двумя!

Comment: А дайте ссылочку на тот вопрос, где выразили несогласие с достаточно очевидной вещью.

Comment: Артем, почему у вас остаются сомнения? Артем, вы - с большой буквы пишется в официальном стиле и при особой вежливости. По-вашему все-таки разговорный вариант, поэтому писать вы - с большой буквы нет смысла.

Comment: На какой вопрос, Ирина?

Comment: Вы же видите, сколько несогласных, Серж.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Артём Луговой, есть одно элементарное правило. 
Слова, написанные через дефис, - это орфографически одно слово.

Так вот, правило такое. В русском языке не может существовать заглавных букв в середине слова (если это не имя собственное, в формах типа пол-Европы, хотя и тут, имхо, плохо смотрится, хорошо бы чего-то изменить).

Этим все сказано. Никакие оправдания ненормативного написания, приводимые в других ответах, не могут быть приняты во внимание.

Дополнение.
Увидела тут у slava1949 пример "по-Божьему". Весьма спорный это пример.
Ни разу с подобным не сталкивалась, кроме словаря Лопатина. Не претендую на широкий кругозор, но даже тут можно толковать Бог как нечто, близкое к имени собственному. Хотя всё равно я с таким написанием не согласна. Какая-то новация Лопатина.

> По-хорошему, это должно быть оговорено в правилах.

А вот тут я с вами совершенно согласна. Должно. Но в правилах вообще нет многого из того, что там должно бы быть, они консервативны, а жизнь не стоит на месте. Ничего не поделаешь, приходится домысливать и ждать новой редакции правил. Но пока там такого нет, лучше не пользоваться. Особенно когда это против твоих собственных убеждений.

Comment: Спасибо, Ирина! Убедили!)

Answer (score 1):

Неверно. Потому что если я пишу "Вы" с большой, то и "по-Вашему" напишу так же.

Comment: Интересно... И как Вы это можете доказать?

Comment: Можно в нацкорпусе посмотреть. Но и так очевидно.

Comment: Посмотрел в Нацкорпусе. До 2003 г. на больше тысячи примеров всего шестнадцать с большой буквы.

Comment: Ну так надо смотреть, где "Вы" с большой и тут же "по-вашему" с маленькой. Такие есть?

Comment: Да, Вы правы, надо посмотреть. Ещё не успел.

Comment: Всё это фигня, никуда не годится. :( Ничего я не нашёл, и вся эта статистика ни о чём не говорит. Дело в том, что там примеры из литературы, где все варианты с "вы" пишут с маленькой буквы. Тут нужны примеры деловой переписки, которую можно взять примером. И даже этого мало. По-хорошему, это должно быть оговорено в правилах. Разве нет? И что, действительно нигде об этом не написано? Жалко, если так.

Answer (score 1):

1. Общей закономерности (в виде признака написания первой части составного слова с заглавной буквы) нет: есть слова типа *пол-Москвы, лже-Дмитрий*.
2. Правило написания с большой буквы при обращениях в некоторых видах документов относится к *местоимениям* **Вы**, **Ваш**. Составное слово "по-вашему" ("как Вы это понимаете", "как Вы настаиваете") местоимением не является и относится к *наречиям*. Прописная буква сохраняется от *имени собственного* в наречиях (обозн. индив. принадлежность) с приставкой по-, образованных от притяжательных прилагательных на **-ин** (*по-Тан**ин**ому*) - из Лопатина ( http://orthographia.ru/orfograf_uk.php?oid=5227 ).
   Случай с местомением *Ваш* сюда не отнести, поэтому для оснований к сохранению в наречии заглавной буквы из местоимения (если такие основания существуют - здесь не замешано имя собственное) надо найти прямое упоминание об этом в нормативных рекомендациях (хотя бы в ведомственных при издательстве).

Comment: Спасибо! Найти бы их, такие рекомендации!..

Answer (score 1):

> “по-Вашему”?

Считаю, что использование прописной в *наречии* ***по-Вашему*** не противоречит правилам.

Да, в ПАС есть [**параграф 166**](https://orfogrammka.ru/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%B8_%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85_%D0%B8_%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85_%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B2/#id-5%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B2-%C2%A7166), в котором речь идёт о написании с прописной прилагательных с суффиксом ***-ин*** и образованных от них наречий (типа *по-Петиному*).

Но словами с ***-ин*** не ограничен перечень прилагательных и наречий, использующих прописную.

И если мы пишем с прописной прилагательное ***Ваш,*** то почему эта прописная должна исчезнуть в образованном от этого прилагательного *наречии*?

Ср.:

[***Божий***](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B9) (суффикса ***-ин*** здесь нет) -> [***по-Божьему.***](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B6%D1%8C%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83&all=x)

.

Из письма [**Михаила Викторовича Панова**](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2,_%D0%9C%D0%B8%D1%85%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%BB_%D0%92%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87) к Н.А. Еськовой (1999 г.):

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо, Слава! Всё вроде верно, но... Что Вы думаете о двух ссылках, которые я нашёл (под номерами 1 и 2)? И не только Вы.

Comment: Думаю, что это личное мнение  двух неведомых мне авторов (а Вам они известны?). Ссылок на правила я у них не нашёл. И почему в "по-Божьему" нужно использовать прописную, они вроде бы тоже не объясняют.

Comment: Нет, я их, конечно, тоже не знаю. Да, насчёт "по-В(в)ашему" я не отстаиваю никакого варианта и не заинтересован, чтобы какой-то определённый "победил", я буду доволен тем, что окажется правильным (хотя, похоже, все уже за большую букву и меня почти убедили), а вот если кто-то будет отстаивать маленькую Б в "по-Божьему", мне это не понравится. Рад, что Вы не из таких (и те сайты, судя по Вашим словам).

Comment: В случае с Богом, хотя он и находится за пределами (условного) ограничения **-ин**, имеет место "**имя** Бога", сила которого распространена за пределы "притяжательности" из тех же правил (по-Божьему без контекста не отличить от "по-Божьи"), и этот случай расходится с "_по-ленински_" и подобными наречиями. В случае же письма, возможно, корректоры просто предпочли воспроизвести автора с его проявлением вежливости в середине наречия, а возможно и руководствовались документом, который мы ищем.

Answer (score 0):

Нет здесь никаких двух точек зрения. Есть одна:

"по-Вашему" на письме при обращении к единственному лицу пишется так же, как местоимение "Вы".

Сравнение с наречием "по-ленински" прискорбно хромает на обе ноги и как точка зрения не подлежит рассмотрению: один коленкор - наречия на -ски/-цки/-ому/-ему/-ки/-ьи, другой - на -ов/-ев/-ин. (Марксистское учение - по-марксистски - Марксов "Капитал" - согласно Марксову "Капиталу"; Далевы труды, Танин учебник, Зевсов гнев, Растреллиев стиль.)

Примеров из переписок с "по-Вашему" не нашла, но есть замечательное опровержение "Усть-Илимску": дядь Ваня, тёть Маня, баб Дуня,

а в притяжательном обличье -

[**ДЯДЯ-ВАСИН**!!!](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%B4%D1%8F%D0%B4%D1%8C-%D0%92%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD)

Сделай-ка по-дядь-Васиному или... тёти-Галиному! )))

Comment: Да, действительно, наречия с приставкой по-, образованные от прилагательных, обозначающих _инд. принадлежность_, пишутся с сохранением большой буквы при соотв. имени собственном (здесь магия имени не выветривается) - есть такое у Лопатина. "По-ленински" отличается по смыслу - убираю эту аргументацию. Остаётся и дальше искать циркуляр: местоимение - не имя собственное, и аналогии с таковым здесь недостаточно.

Comment: Спасибо! Повеселили, теть-Галь!)))

Comment: Тёмыч, я ошибку допустила - налепила дефисов в именительном падеже! вместо притяжательного... Прости, друг! А чего нашла!.. "по-его, по-её, по-их, по-жюль-верновски, по-тёти-Валиному; так же пишутся образованные от существительных наречия по-латыни (читать по-латыни, т. е. на латинском языке, но: занятие по латыни), по-матери, по-матушке (матом), по-человечеству".

Comment: Саша, местоимение в личном обращении соотносится с именем, как имя и прозвище... Так я думаю.